# Group a table with a junction table

Tags: sql, oracle, select-query, junction-table

I have a table EVENT and a table ATTENDEE. When grouped by its lookup values EVENT looks like this:

```
|EVENT_ID|EVENT_TYPE|CITY|STATE|ZIP|
```

Many events can have many attendees, so I then have an EVENT_ATTENDEE junction table:

```
|EVENT_ID|ATTENDEE_ID|
```

I want to display the relevant contents of the EVENT table. My results would look something like this:

```
|EVENT_ID|EVENT_TYPE|CITY|STATE|ZIP|ATTENDEE_1|ATTENDEE_2|...|ATTENDEE_N|
```

Is there a way in SQL to accomplish this task?

Comment: Where are the rows of data?

Comment: I didn't include any in the example cause I thought it was unnecessary.

Comment: Why do you want a stored procedure?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I never said I wanted a stored procedure for this task. My thoughts would be a single select query that took the rows of a junction table and appended them to be columns of the respective 'parent' table ( I don't know what else to call it)

Comment: By saying PL/SQL you are stating that you want a stored procedure. PL/SQL is a procedural language.

Comment: We're using the Oracle 11g for a database. Its brand SQL is PLSQL. I said nothing about stored procedures

Comment: PL/SQL and SQL are different things. [PL/SQL is Oracle's procedural extension to SQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PL/SQL). PL/SQL is _not_ the name of Oracle's SQL dialect. As soon as you mention PL/SQL in this context you're effectively talking about stored procedures or functions.